# What are the essential differences and similarities among "data", "Information" and "knowledge" in the context of Computer Science?

Tags: database-theory, databases, knowledge-representation

The terms "data", "information" and "knowledge" are quite interchangeably used in Computer Science. Strictly speaking, they do carry a very different meaning. I want to know their precise meanings and their context and usage.

According to my limited experience, data is simply "raw fact and figures" whereas information is "meaningful data" and knowledge is information via which one can predict the unknown or infer something new. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: "The terms "data", "information" and "knowledge" are quite interchangeably used in Computer Science." -- I would say only when talking very loosely to those outside the profession. Have you looked at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data or https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/information/ or the distinction https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_Ryle#Knowing-how_and_knowing-that ? I think you should make your q more specific; as currently it's really asking for an opinion.

Comment: I think specifically in CS, "data" is the least ambiguous term. Namely, it is anything which can be written down (stored) and then reliably read back by anyone. As such, "data" handling is a strict and special case of information transfer.

Comment: Yes, that are actual opinions. But new results were found! Look one step deeper.

Answer (score 2):

All are main topics in Information Science.

**Information**

a) needs Human Being, without Human Being no Information

b) Information can be stored in Data for Computer

**Data**

a) stored Information

b) makes possible that Information can be retrieved by computer as machines

c) can be dead (stored for computer) or living (inside the human Being or any other living organism)

**Knowledge**

Is that Information wich is stored inside Human Being.
The biological neuronal organs are Human Nerves and Brain.
Philosophical name for it Human Memory.

Answer (score 1):

You're description is pretty accurate. There is no formal definition or precise meaning coming from a high level. There are only formal definitions in specific fields such as information theory for Information (bits) and knowledge such as in cognitive architectures. Data doesn't have a precise meaning either, haven't seen a formal model of that in any case.

Comment: It´s a main topic in new reorganised Information Science to define the names or words Information, Data and Knowledge in a scientific, worldwide unified way.  See my answer one step deeper. That´s not easy, but I think its was possible.